# Diffuse bake turns out black

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I'm trying to bake out this mesh to export into a game engine, and the diffuse bake turns out black. I know I'm doing everything correctly because if I bake the roughness it turns out fine. Does anyone know a solution? I've included pictures of all my materials and the mesh.

[image: mesh]

[image: Slide material]

[image: safety indicator]
[image: Gold]
[image: regular black]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you explain the exact steps you use to do the bake?

Comment: @MartyFouts I set the render engine to cycles, made sure bake was set to diffuse, selected my mesh, selected my image texture node of choice, and clicked bake

Comment: @Blunder Yes, it did! thank you so much